# [SOLVED]There are 10 boys and 12 girls in a class. How many ways are there to select three class representatives, such that both genders are involved?

Tags: combinatorics

Currently, I am stuck in this combination problem as I am not sure how to find out all the possibilities (there are certainly a lot). However, this problem is due tomorrow.
Edit: is the answer 1200? since total combinations: 1540- 120 (only boys combination)- 220 (only girls combination).
2 Edit: SOLVED, thanks for all your help

Comment: Hint: There can either be $1$ boy and $2$ girls or $1$ girl and $2$ boys as class representatives.

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer is the answer 1200? since total combinations: 1540- 120 (only boys combination)- 220 (only girls combination). Thanks a lot for your hint :)

Comment: @KongMing Yes :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. One is the way you did it:

$$\binom{22}3-\binom{12}3-\binom{10}3 = 1540-220-120 = 1200.$$

Another way is to say: there could be two boys and one girl, or two girls and one boy: $$\binom{10}2\cdot12+
\binom{12}2\cdot 10 = 540+660=1200.$$

This is a little simpler, and also a little more useful, because it tells you how many groups there are with each distribution of boys and girls.

A third way says: we must pick one girl and one boy, and then one more
person from the remaining 20:
$$12\cdot10
\cdot 20=1200\cdot 2$$ but we have to divide by 2 because that counts each possible group of three exactly twice.